# How to do a calculation using order of columns

Tags: r

I am  trying to add an additional column that shows the percentage change using 2 columns in a data frame.

For example, let's say that my data frame has 13 columns with 2 rows for each. and row values are all numeric. I am trying to come up with 14th column that results are from a calculation using 13th and 12th columns.

Would this work?

```
df$additionalcolumn <- (df[,13] - df[,12]) / df[,12]
```

Comment: Have you tried it? was the result what you expected?

Comment: I found another problem trying the code answered by people below. The reason calculation is not working is that the data is in 'factor' format. I somehow need to change the format to numeric value. Any idea?

Comment: convert to string using `as.character()` and then to numeric using `as.numeric()`. However I would suggest to instead look at your data source and how you are reading these data into R to make sure it is correct. You may find the `readr` package helpful since it's read functions are more verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran this sample code and it worked fine. Try it

```
test = data.frame(a=seq(1,10), b=seq(10,19))
test$c = test[,1] + test[,2]
print(test)
```

Output

```
    a  b  c
1   1 10 11
2   2 11 13
3   3 12 15
4   4 13 17
5   5 14 19
6   6 15 21
7   7 16 23
8   8 17 25
9   9 18 27
10 10 19 29
```

Comment: I found another problem trying the code above. The reason calculation is not working is that the data is in 'factor' format. I somehow need to change the format to numeric value. Any idea?

Comment: You can do `test$b = as.numeric(as.character(test$b))`. This converts your factor to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Or via `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) # load the necessary packages
test = data.table(a=seq(1,10), b=seq(10,19)) #create the data.table
test[,c:=a+b]#create a new column named c and fill it with the sum of a and b
```